# Identify pieces from parts list from a video

Tags: part-identification

I have a screenshot of instructions from a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ln-Y48olr5U) that include a parts list, but unfortunately no part numbers/names.

My own experience with LEGO is limited, but I was looking for a way to identify these parts to be able to buy them and make it into a gift for a LEGO and AoE2 enthusiast.

Do you have any suggestion on a good way to reliably identify these parts?

[image]

**EDIT**
I have changed the picture and added numbers to the parts for easier reference. I think I am already able to identify most of them through https://brickognize.com, bricklink.com and [LEGO's pick-a-brick](https://www.lego.com/de-de/pick-and-build/pick-a-brick), but here are the parts I am unsure about:

- 2,6,13 all have a slightly lighter shade than the dark brown parts (which I have put as Reddish Brown) I would have guessed the lighter shade might be Dark Red, but would welcome some input
- 24, 30, 34 I am unsure which color this is supposed to be, maybe Dark Orange?
- 3, I am also unsure about the color - bright yellow maybe?
- 15 I am unsure. The closest I can think of was [Brick, Round 1 x 1 Solid Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062a&name=Brick,%20Round%201%20x%201%20Solid%20Stud&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=C), but it looks a bit like the sides are not smooth, so I am unsure
- 26 I couldn't find
- 31, this seems to be [Body Microfigure Complete](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85863&name=Body%20Microfigure%20Complete&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Part%5D#T=C) but I couldn't find it on pick-a-brick
- 35, I think it is [Fence 1 x 4 x 1 Lattice](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3633&name=Fence%201%20x%204%20x%201%20Lattice&category=%5BFence%5D#T=C) but would welcome confirmation
- 11, 13, 20, 40 I could identify, but didn't find it on pick-a-brick to order - does that mean I misidentified or that it is not produced anymore?

Comment: Which of these parts are you having trouble identifying? Can you mark it somehow, like circling it in the image? Most of them are very basic ones and so identifying all of them would probably be a waste of time.

Comment: @zovits thanks for the comment. Should have highlighted from the start. Let me check and edit accordingly

Comment: @zovits I have gotten around to editing as per your request. There are now small numbers next to the parts in the picture. I think with circles the picture might have become less readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some answers on Bricklink, Rebrickable and other sources:

| # | Amount | Name | Part # | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 13 | Tile 1 x 1 with Groove | 3070, 30039, 35403, 39727, 53836 | Reddish Brown |
| 2. | 4 | Tile 1 x 1 with Groove | 3070, 30039, 35403, 39727, 53836 | Dark Red |
| 3. | 1 | Tile, Round 1 x 1 | 98138, 35380, 35381, 39797 | Pearl Gold |
| 4. | 1 | Plate 1 x 1 | 3024, 28554, 30008, 63326 | Reddish Brown |
| 5. | 106 | Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3 | 54200, 18862, 33847, 35338, 50746, 63290 | Reddish Brown |
| 6. | 56 | Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3 | 54200, 18862, 33847, 35338, 50746, 63290 | Dark Red |
| 7. | 9 | Tile, Modified 1 x 2 Grille with Bottom Groove / Lip | 15561, 30244, 35248, 51815, 71957, 72582, 78812 | Reddish Brown |
| 8. | 6 | Plate 1 x 2 | 3023, 6225, 28653 | Reddish Brown |
| 9. | 2 | Plate 1 x 2 | 3023, 6225, 28653 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 10. | 4 | Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove and Bottom Stud Holder (Jumper) | 15573, 78823 | Reddish Brown |
| 11. | 15 | Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Horizontal | 49668, 35162, 49673 | Reddish Brown |
| 12. | 4 | Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove and Bottom Stud Holder (Jumper) | 15573, 78823 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 13. | 1 | Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Horizontal | 49668, 35162, 49673 | Dark Red |
| 14. | 20 | Brick 1 x 1 | 3005, 30071, 35382 | Reddish Brown |
| 15. | 1 | Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud | 3062b, 18860, 30068, 35390 | Reddish Brown |
| 16. | 24 | Brick 1 x 1 | 3005, 30071, 35382 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 17. | 18 | Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Stud on Side | 87087 | Dark Bluish Gray |
| 18. | 1 | Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Groove and 1 Stud in Center (Jumper) | 87580 | Reddish Brown |
| 19. | 2 | Slope 45 2 x 1 | 3040 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 20. | 2 | Minifigure, Weapon Knife | 44658a | Dark Bluish Gray |
| 21. | 6 | Brick 1 x 2 | 3004 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 22. | 68<sup>1</sup> | Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Masonry Profile | 98283 | Dark Bluish Gray |
| 23. | 1 | Plate 1 x 4 | 3710 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 24. | 2 | Plate 2 x 3 | 3021 | Dark Orange |
| 25. | 2 | Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Open O Clip Thick (Vertical Grip) | 42925 | Dark Bluish Gray |
| 26. | 2 | Bar 3L (Bar Arrow) | 87994, 17715, 19385, 37078 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 27. | 12 | Brick 1 x 3 | 3622 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 28. | 20 | Slope 45 2 x 2 | 3039 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 29. | 4 | Slope 45 2 x 2 Double Convex Corner | 3045 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 30. | 2 | Slope, Inverted 45 2 x 2 Double Convex | 3676 | Dark Orange |
| 31. | 2 | Body Microfigure Complete | 85863 | White |
| 32. | 7 | Plate 2 x 4 | 3020 | Reddish Brown |
| 33. | 6 | Plate 2 x 4 | 3020 | Bright Blue |
| 34. | 4 | Plate 2 x 4 | 3020 | Dark Orange |
| 35. | 6 | Fence 1 x 4 x 1 Lattice | 3633 | Reddish Brown |
| 36. | 6 | Window 1 x 2 x 2 Flat Front | 60592 | Reddish Brown |
| 37. | 1 | Brick 1 x 2 x 2 | 3245c | Light Bluish Gray |
| 38. | 3 | Plate 1 x 6 | 3666 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 39. | 2 | Plate 2 x 6 | 3795 | Reddish Brown |
| 40. | 2 | Minifigure, Shield Ovoid | 2586 | Bright Blue |
| 41. | 2 | Plate 1 x 8 | 3460 | Bright Blue |
| 42. | 12 | Plate 1 x 8 | 3460 | Reddish brown |
| 43. | 6 | Plate 1 x 8 | 3460 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 44. | 6 | Slope, Inverted 75 2 x 1 x 3 | 2449 | Reddish Brown |
| 45. | 2 | Panel 1 x 2 x 3 - Hollow Studs | 2362b, 30009b | Reddish Brown |
| 46. | 4 | Plate 2 x 8 | 3034 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 47. | 2 | Brick 1 x 8 | 3008 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 48. | 2 | Plate 1 x 10 | 4477 | Light Bluish Gray |
| 49. | 2 | Arch 1 x 6 x 2 - Medium Thick Top without Reinforced Underside | 15254 | Dark Bluish Gray |

---

**Notes**:

1. Picture shows incorrect amount. You need 68 pieces of Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Masonry Profile to actually build that model. Checking individual steps the number of bricks adds up to 68.

Comment: Thanks for taking the initiative! If by your last sentence you mean "other users can add more pieces that I couldn't recognize" then you can explicitly invite others to do so by setting the answer to a [community wiki](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), that can be easily edited by anyone.

Comment: thank you for this first list. Helped me a lot to get started in the right direction. I have edited my question to highlight the once I have most trouble with and also assigned numbers to the bricks.

Comment: I turn on my community wiki for some more fan-genearared edits on my answer.

Comment: I have added my current status of research. Is the color you put as LBG the "Light Blue Grey" from bricklink and equivalent to what Lego calls "Medium Stone Grey" on pick-a-brick

Comment: @Auther No I meant "Light Bluish Gray" on my BL.

Comment: @FlyingTeller : "Light Bluish Grey" and "Medium Stone Grey" are indeed different names for one and the same color.

Comment: Great collaboration everyone :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for contributing